# Struggling with objects, program does not work as expected(java)

Tags: java, object-reference

So I have this cyclingmanager game, and I want to show a list of riders by names, and then I want to show their abilities when the user picks a rider. The program compiles and runs nicely, the problem is in my riders() method.It just does not print out c1, my first rider. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CyclingManager2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //menyvalgene
    Menu m = new Menu();

    m.choice();


    }
}

class Menu {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Cyclist cy = new Cyclist();

//choices
public void choice() {

    int choice = -1;
    while (choice != 0) {

        System.out.println("Choose something: ");
        System.out.println("-0 will exit the program" + "\n-Pressing 1 will open the database menu");
        choice = in.nextInt();
        switch(choice) {
            case 0: choice = 0; break;
            case 1: database(); break;
            default: System.out.println("You have to choose either 0 or 1"); break;
            }

        }
    }
public void database() {

    System.out.println("Welcome to the database \nThese are the options:\n0 = Back to menu\n1: Riders");
    int dbChoice = -1;

    while (dbChoice != 0) {

        System.out.println();
        dbChoice = in.nextInt();
        switch(dbChoice) {
            case 0: dbChoice = 0; break;
            case 1: cy.riders(); System.out.println("Press 0 for going back to the menu\nPress 1 for showing the riders");break;
            default: System.out.println("Choose either 0 or 1"); break;
        }

    } 
}

}

class Cyclist {

List<Cyclist> cyclists = new ArrayList<>(); 
private String name;
private int mountain;
private int timeTrial;
private int sprint;
private int age;
Cyclist c1 = null;


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setMountain(int mountain) {
    this.mountain = mountain;
}

public int getMountain() {
    return mountain;
}


public void setTimeTrial(int timeTrial) {
    this.timeTrial = timeTrial;
}

public int getTimeTrial() {
    return timeTrial;
}

public void setSprint(int sprint) {
    this.sprint = sprint;
}

public int getSprint() {
    return sprint;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}


public void riders() {
    abilities();
    for (int i = 0; i < cyclists.size(); i++){
          System.out.print(((Cyclist) cyclists).getName());
    }

}



public void abilities() {

    //Pardilla is created

    c1 = new Cyclist();
    c1.setName("Sergio Pardilla");
    c1.setMountain(75);
    c1.setTimeTrial(60);
    c1.setSprint(60);
    c1.setAge(30);

    /*System.out.println(c1.getName() + "'s abilities:");
    System.out.println("Mountain - " + c1.getMountain());
    System.out.println("TimeTrial - " + c1.getTimeTrial());
    System.out.println("Sprint - " + c1.getSprint());
    System.out.println("Age - " +c1.getAge());

    cyclists.add(c1); //adds Pardilla to cyclists arraylist*/
    }

}
```

Comment: The riders() method should print out the arraylist names, such as Sergio Pardilla(c1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want more something like:

```
public void riders() {
    abilities();
    for (int i = 0; i < cyclists.size(); i++){
          System.out.print(cyclists.get(i).getName());
    }
}
```

Another thing, is that I'm not sure you want `List<Cyclist> cyclists = new ArrayList<>();`  to be part of `Cyclist` class.

Comment: Easiest solution as I prefer common for loops over the enhanched version. Thank you very much, this is THE answer I used to improve my program.

Answer (score 3):

You have this for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cyclists.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(((Cyclist) cyclists).getName());
}
```

It is not going to work. You are casting the entire `cyclists` (an `ArrayList`) to one `cyclist` instance. You probably want to iterate over the contents of the `ArrayList` and get each `Cyclist`-object in the `cyclists` array. Try a foreach-loop:

```
for (Cyclist cyclist : cyclists) {
    System.out.print(cyclist.getName());
}
```

or use a for loop with index based retrieval:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cyclists.size(); i++) {
    cyclists.get(i).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. The part where you add your rider to the `ArrayList` is commented out.
2. The way you loop over your `ArrayList` is by no means correct. Try like this:

   ```
   for (Cyclist cyclist : cyclists) {
       System.out.println(cyclist.getName());
   }
   ```

Comment: I commented it out in order to not face a run-time error. Thanks for your answer <3

Answer (score 0):

You should get Objects from List by calling it number: `cyclists.get(i).getName())`